# Animating a Card's height

Tags: flutter

I have a simple `Card` with an "Expand" button that toggles visibility of an `_expandedCardBody` method that returns a `Column`.

```
  bool expandedCard = false;

  Widget _expandedCardBody() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(...),
        Row(...),
        Row(...),
      ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Setup my budget", style: kTitleStyle),
                Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        leading: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/images/icon-eating-out.svg",
                            width: 65),
                        title: Text('Eating out', style: kNormalStyle),
                        subtitle:
                            Text('AED 1,245 this month', style: kSmallStyle),
                        trailing: SizedBox(
                          width: 75,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "AED.."),
                            style: kNormalStyle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      expandedCard ? _expandedCardBody() : SizedBox(),
                      Divider(),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: FlatButton(
                          child: Text(expandedCard ? 'COLLAPSE' : 'EXPAND'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              expandedCard = !expandedCard;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
```

It works, but this is what it looks like:

[image: no animation]

Instead of simply showing/hiding `_expandedCardBody`, I'd like to animate it's height.

I've tried using `AnimatedContainer` like so, but it requires knowing the height of the _expandedCardBody (which I do not).

```
AnimatedContainer(
  child: _expandedCardBody(),
  height: expandedCard ? 200 : 0, //  don't know what the height is.
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
),
```

How can I animate the height of the Card body?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SingleTickerProvider` with your state class

for eg like this :

```
 class YourClass extends State<YourClass>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  var isDetailOpened = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), vsync: this);
    _animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    seeMoreEnabled = false;
    animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

then Replace your `Text` (Expand or collapse) with `flatButton` or `CupertinoButton`

after doing that `onPress` or `onClick` method

```
 onPressed: () {
                  if (isDetailOpened) {
                    _animationController.reverse();
                  } else {
                    _animationController.forward();
                  }
                  isDetailOpened = !isDetailOpened;
                },
```

after that Put your widgets in `SizeTransition`

```
 SizeTransition(
            axisAlignment: 1.0,
            sizeFactor: animation,
             (your other widgets)
```

**This is an example for an ideal purpose (in simply way)**

Comment: This seems overly disruptive for what looks like a simple issue. Why can't I just make this work with `AnimatedContainer`?

Comment: well, you can also use it but for me, this is Lil bit easy